# Evaluating an math expression in Postfix (RPN) Java. No stack, only strings

Tags: java, regex, infix-notation, calc, rpn

I'm trying to make some sense of the following instructions using a subroutine:

i = 1

while i<= n

if v_i is an operand: Push v_i to tmp2.

if v_i is an operator: Apply v_i to the top two elements of
tmp2. Replace these by the result in tmp2.

i = i + 1
 Output result from tmp2.

So basically I'm trying to calculate some expression in postfix(RPN) form. Here I want whenever the digit is an operand(number) to be transferred to tmp2, and when there's an operator repalce it by the valuse in tmp2. e.g. 3 5 1  +8 / 14* = 14

other problems: whatever I write, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutO...." error.
v_i is a digit or operator or parentheses.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

My code:

```
static int eval(String postfix){
    int  result = 0;
    String temp2 ="";

    for (int i=0 ; i<postfix.length(); i++) {
        if (postfix.charAt(i)  !=')' && postfix.charAt(i)!= '(' && postfix.charAt(i)!= p(infix.charAt(i)))
            temp2 += postfix.charAt(i);

        int num1,num2;
        char operator;

            do { 
                i++;            
            } while ( Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(i)));

            num1 = Integer.parseInt(postfix.substring(0,i));
            operator = postfix.charAt(i++);
            num2 = //Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(i));
                Integer.parseInt(postfix.substring(i+1));



            result = num1 + num2;
            result = num1 - num2;
            result = num1 * num2;
            result = num1 / num2;

            switch (operator) {

            case '+' : result = num1 + num2; break;
            case '-' : result = num1 - num2; break;
            case '*' : result = num1 * num2; break;
            case '/' : result = num1 / num2; break;



            }


    }




    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't evaluate postfix or any other kind of -fix without a stack. Unclear what you're asking. Are you expected to somehow use a string as a stack? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

It means you are trying to access a character outside of your char array, ie the length of your char array is 10 and you're trying to get the 11th character.

A better approach for your problem would be to first tokenize your expression using either String.split or StringTokenizer [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), then loop through each token:

- if token is an operand push into a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)--Java has a Stack class, so use that.
- if token is an operator, pop operands from stack and perform the operation, push the answer back into the stack.

Comment: Thanks! But the point of the assignment is to use String manipulation.

Comment: I would argue that String.split or StringTokenize are ways to manipulate strings.  If you have to loop through each character and not using Stack to evaluate your expression then I think you are wasting your time.  No-one in their right mind should expect you to do that.